# Equivalence of the persistence landscape diagram and the barcode?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, computational-mathematics, data-analysis, topological-data-analysis

I am studying persistent homology for the first time. I was reading Peter Bubenik's paper "Statistical Topological Data Analysis using Persistence Landscapes" from 2015 introducing persistent landscapes. I am quite confused on the approach on finding the values of the persistence landscape function using a barcode/persistence diagram. I feel like I have a naive misunderstanding of this topic as I shall attempt to explain.

Suppose $X$ is a finite set of points in Euclidean space. From my understanding, if we consider the (finite length) persistence vector space given by the simplicial complex homology for a fixed dimension $l$, $\{H_l(X_k)\}_{k=1}^n$ with maps $\{\delta_{k,k'}\}$, for $1\leq k,k'\leq n$, we have
$$\{H_l(X_k)\}_{k=1}^n\cong\oplus_{i=1}^m \mathbb{I}(b_i, d_i)$$
(Theorem 4.10 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.13400)) for some multiset $\{(b_i, d_i)\}_{i=1}^m$, where $\mathbb{I}(b,d)$ gives the persistence vector space of length $n$,
$$0\rightarrow ... \rightarrow 0\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\rightarrow... \rightarrow 0 ... \rightarrow 0$$
with non-zero vector spaces at values of the specified interval.

This multiset corresponds to the persistence diagram/barcode so that the $k$-th Betti number can be identified by finding the number of lines of the barcode that intersect the line $x=k$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Now Bubenik defines the Betti number of the persistence vector space for an interval $[a,b]$ by
$\beta^{a,b}=\dim(\text{im}(\delta_{a,b}))$, and the persistence landscape functions $\lambda_k:\mathbb{R}\to [-\infty,\infty]$, for $k\in\mathbb{N}$ by
$$\lambda_k(t) = \sup \{m\geq 0 \mid \beta^{t-m, t+m}\geq k\}$$

Shouldn't $\beta^{t-m, t+m}$ then correspond to the number of lines on the barcode that contain the interval $[t-m, t+m]$, so that $\lambda_k(t)$ is the largest value of $m$ that has at least $k$ lines of the barcode intersecting $[t-m,t+m]$?

I am confused on how the triangle construction is equivalent to the persistence landscape function instead. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Everything you say seems to be correct.  Have you tried computing the persistence landscapes by hand for small examples?  Also, in this case it's more useful to think about the persistent diagram instead of the barcode; recall $\beta^{t-m,t+m}$ is also the number of points on the diagram contained in the upper left quadrant bound by the lines $x = t - m$ and $y = t + m$.

Comment: @JHF Yes, I was taking a look at these slides by Bubenik 
https://icerm.brown.edu/materials/Slides/tri17-1-gtd/Persistence_Landscapes_and_the_Geometry_of_Data_]_Peter_Bubenik,_University_of_Florida.pdf

and on slide number 11, there's an example given, which does not support my understanding. In particular, at x=10, it has a value of y=4, when I would expect a value of 0. I haven't thought about it in terms of the persistence diagram though, I'll definitely look into that. My confusion is with the relation with the Betti numbers.

Comment: On that slide, we have $\lambda_1(10) = 4$ because an interval centered at $t = 10$ with radius $m = 4$ (but no larger), i.e., $(6,14)$, still contains $k = 1$ complete bar from the barcode.

Comment: @JHF Oh yes, you're right. I tried to look up more counterexamples and I think I  replaced the horizontal width with the Betti value earlier and got myself confused. This is what happens when you think about these things late at night lol. Sorry for wasting your time and I appreciate your help! If you add this as an answer, I'd be happy to select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read off the value of the landscape function $\lambda_k(t)$ from the barcode for fixed $k$, imagine expanding an interval centered at $t$.  A small interval might be contained in many bars of the barcode, but as the interval grows, fewer and fewer bars of the barcode can contain all of it.  Continue expanding the interval until just before it is contained in only $k - 1$ bars.  The radius $m$ of that interval is equal to $\lambda_k(t)$.

Of course, I prefer to obtain landscapes from persistence diagrams.  To do this, drop two lines down and right from each point on the diagram to the diagonal and rotate the entire picture $45^\circ$ clockwise.  Imagine the "diagonal" (which is now horizontal) as the $t$-axis and the vertical distance as the $m$-axis.  What you see formed from the lines you drew is the union of the graphs of the functions $\lambda_k(t)$ for $k \geq 1$.  The topmost ridge formed from the lines is the graph of $\lambda_1$, the second topmost ridge formed is the graph of $\lambda_2$, and so on.